# How to tell if freeze and mint authority are revoked?

Tags: solana-program

For example the token below - it does not show auth: 111111111111111111111, instead it doesn't even show.

https://solscan.io/token/8jFzPydsFBKPMvVrVBZCkgp84xRKAKYxEBemF9MF2dSk?cluster=devnet#txs

Answer (score 1):

You can see the mint and close authority on SolanaFM for example:

https://solana.fm/address/8jFzPydsFBKPMvVrVBZCkgp84xRKAKYxEBemF9MF2dSk?cluster=devnet-solana

You can also use js:

```
const info = await connection.getAccountInfo(mintkeyPair.publicKey, "confirmed");
const unpackedMint =  unpackMint(mintkeyPair.publicKey, info, TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID);

console.log("mintInfo", unpackedMint);
```

Which will give you the mint info:

```
mintInfo {
  address: PublicKey [PublicKey(6VbtNX6eAHWT4PSE6dBD4kYCTtdeUB7g6pU8Wq9VBQGp)] {
    _bn: <BN: 519e2486b9267182f46f2fa5a504528110851a7fe5cbc62967e19d36818867a1>
  },
  mintAuthority: PublicKey [PublicKey(5vJwnLeyjV8uNJSp1zn7VLW8GwiQbcsQbGaVSwRmkE4r)] {
    _bn: <BN: 4916d20d019fe32a08c4facde04ed651a95b3798ed738891df27f4e610cbe02b>
  },
  supply: 0n,
  decimals: 9,
  isInitialized: true,
  freezeAuthority: PublicKey [PublicKey(5vJwnLeyjV8uNJSp1zn7VLW8GwiQbcsQbGaVSwRmkE4r)] {
    _bn: <BN: 4916d20d019fe32a08c4facde04ed651a95b3798ed738891df27f4e610cbe02b>
  },
  tlvData: <Buffer >
}
```